# Error loading cl-unicode

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I assume I must be missing something, rather new to this. Quicklisp update-dist and update-client say I have the latest, loaded cl-ppcre just before and it worked fine. SBCL version is 1.3.8 and I'm on Windows 7, if this is relevant. Any pointers appreciated.

```
* (ql:quickload :cl-unicode)
To load "cl-unicode":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-unicode
; Loading "cl-unicode"
.
; file: C:/Users/K/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-unicode-0.1.5/util.lisp
; in: DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "SBase"
;     (CL-UNICODE::DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "SBase" 44032)
; --> EVAL-WHEN
; ==>
;   (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA
;     (CL-UNICODE::CREATE-SYMBOL CL-UNICODE::NAME)
;     :COMMA
;     CL-UNICODE::VALUE
;     :COMMA
;     (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book."
;             CL-UNICODE::NAME))
;
; caught ERROR:
;   (during macroexpansion of (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA ...))
;   error while parsing arguments to DEFMACRO DEFCONSTANT:
;     too many elements in
;       (:COMMA (CREATE-SYMBOL NAME) :COMMA VALUE :COMMA
;        (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book." NAME))
;     to satisfy lambda list
;       (SB-IMPL::NAME SB-IMPL::VALUE &OPTIONAL (SB-IMPL::DOC)):
;     between 2 and 3 expected, but got 6

; in: DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "LBase"
;     (CL-UNICODE::DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "LBase" 4352)
; --> EVAL-WHEN
; ==>
;   (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA
;     (CL-UNICODE::CREATE-SYMBOL CL-UNICODE::NAME)
;     :COMMA
;     CL-UNICODE::VALUE
;     :COMMA
;     (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book."
;             CL-UNICODE::NAME))
;
; caught ERROR:
;   (during macroexpansion of (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA ...))
;   error while parsing arguments to DEFMACRO DEFCONSTANT:
;     too many elements in
;       (:COMMA (CREATE-SYMBOL NAME) :COMMA VALUE :COMMA
;        (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book." NAME))
;     to satisfy lambda list
;       (SB-IMPL::NAME SB-IMPL::VALUE &OPTIONAL (SB-IMPL::DOC)):
;     between 2 and 3 expected, but got 6

; in: DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "VBase"
;     (CL-UNICODE::DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "VBase" 4449)
; --> EVAL-WHEN
; ==>
;   (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA
;     (CL-UNICODE::CREATE-SYMBOL CL-UNICODE::NAME)
;     :COMMA
;     CL-UNICODE::VALUE
;     :COMMA
;     (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book."
;             CL-UNICODE::NAME))
;
; caught ERROR:
;   (during macroexpansion of (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA ...))
;   error while parsing arguments to DEFMACRO DEFCONSTANT:
;     too many elements in
;       (:COMMA (CREATE-SYMBOL NAME) :COMMA VALUE :COMMA
;        (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book." NAME))
;     to satisfy lambda list
;       (SB-IMPL::NAME SB-IMPL::VALUE &OPTIONAL (SB-IMPL::DOC)):
;     between 2 and 3 expected, but got 6

; in: DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "TBase"
;     (CL-UNICODE::DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "TBase" 4519)
; --> EVAL-WHEN
; ==>
;   (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA
;     (CL-UNICODE::CREATE-SYMBOL CL-UNICODE::NAME)
;     :COMMA
;     CL-UNICODE::VALUE
;     :COMMA
;     (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book."
;             CL-UNICODE::NAME))
;
; caught ERROR:
;   (during macroexpansion of (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA ...))
;   error while parsing arguments to DEFMACRO DEFCONSTANT:
;     too many elements in
;       (:COMMA (CREATE-SYMBOL NAME) :COMMA VALUE :COMMA
;        (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book." NAME))
;     to satisfy lambda list
;       (SB-IMPL::NAME SB-IMPL::VALUE &OPTIONAL (SB-IMPL::DOC)):
;     between 2 and 3 expected, but got 6

; in: DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "VCount"
;     (CL-UNICODE::DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "VCount" 21)
; --> EVAL-WHEN
; ==>
;   (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA
;     (CL-UNICODE::CREATE-SYMBOL CL-UNICODE::NAME)
;     :COMMA
;     CL-UNICODE::VALUE
;     :COMMA
;     (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book."
;             CL-UNICODE::NAME))
;
; caught ERROR:
;   (during macroexpansion of (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA ...))
;   error while parsing arguments to DEFMACRO DEFCONSTANT:
;     too many elements in
;       (:COMMA (CREATE-SYMBOL NAME) :COMMA VALUE :COMMA
;        (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book." NAME))
;     to satisfy lambda list
;       (SB-IMPL::NAME SB-IMPL::VALUE &OPTIONAL (SB-IMPL::DOC)):
;     between 2 and 3 expected, but got 6

; in: DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "TCount"
;     (CL-UNICODE::DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "TCount" 28)
; --> EVAL-WHEN
; ==>
;   (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA
;     (CL-UNICODE::CREATE-SYMBOL CL-UNICODE::NAME)
;     :COMMA
;     CL-UNICODE::VALUE
;     :COMMA
;     (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book."
;             CL-UNICODE::NAME))
;
; caught ERROR:
;   (during macroexpansion of (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA ...))
;   error while parsing arguments to DEFMACRO DEFCONSTANT:
;     too many elements in
;       (:COMMA (CREATE-SYMBOL NAME) :COMMA VALUE :COMMA
;        (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book." NAME))
;     to satisfy lambda list
;       (SB-IMPL::NAME SB-IMPL::VALUE &OPTIONAL (SB-IMPL::DOC)):
;     between 2 and 3 expected, but got 6

; in: DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "NCount"
;     (CL-UNICODE::DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT "NCount"
;                                         (* CL-UNICODE::+V-COUNT+
;                                            CL-UNICODE::+T-COUNT+))
; --> EVAL-WHEN
; ==>
;   (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA
;     (CL-UNICODE::CREATE-SYMBOL CL-UNICODE::NAME)
;     :COMMA
;     CL-UNICODE::VALUE
;     :COMMA
;     (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book."
;             CL-UNICODE::NAME))
;
; caught ERROR:
;   (during macroexpansion of (DEFCONSTANT :COMMA ...))
;   error while parsing arguments to DEFMACRO DEFCONSTANT:
;     too many elements in
;       (:COMMA (CREATE-SYMBOL NAME) :COMMA VALUE :COMMA
;        (FORMAT NIL "The constant `~A' from chapter 3 of the Unicode book." NAME))
;     to satisfy lambda list
;       (SB-IMPL::NAME SB-IMPL::VALUE &OPTIONAL (SB-IMPL::DOC)):
;     between 2 and 3 expected, but got 6
.
debugger invoked on a UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {100299C713}>:
  COMPILE-FILE-ERROR while compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cl-unicode/base" "util">

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY                        ] Retry
                                     compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cl-unicode/base" "util">.
  1: [ACCEPT                       ] Continue, treating
                                     compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cl-unicode/base" "util">
                                     as having been successful.
  2:                                 Retry ASDF operation.
  3: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the configuration.
  4: [ABORT                        ] Give up on "cl-unicode"
  5:                                 Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(UIOP/LISP-BUILD:CHECK-LISP-COMPILE-RESULTS NIL T T "~/asdf-action::format-action/" ((#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:COMPILE-OP > . #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "cl-unicode/base" "util">)))
0] 4
;
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 2 fatal ERROR conditions
;   caught 7 ERROR conditions

("cl-unicode")
*
```

Edit: The plot thickens. Now this also happened:

```
* (ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")
To load "quicklisp-slime-helper":
  Install 3 Quicklisp releases:
    alexandria quicklisp-slime-helper slime
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/slime/2016-05-31/slime-v2.18.tgz">
; 1076.19KB
==================================================
1,102,017 bytes in 3.68 seconds (292.28KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/alexandria/2016-08-25/alexandria-20160825-git.tgz">
; 49.63KB
==================================================
50,819 bytes in 0.31 seconds (160.09KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/quicklisp-slime-helper/2015-07-09/quicklisp-slime-helper-20150709-git.tgz">
; 2.16KB
==================================================
2,211 bytes in 0.00 seconds (1079.59KB/sec)
; Loading "quicklisp-slime-helper"
[package swank-loader]..While evaluating the form starting at line 151, column 0
  of #P"C:/Users/K/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-v2.18/swank-loader.lisp":

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {100299C713}>:
  :COMMA is not allowed as a directory component.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY                        ] Retry EVAL of current toplevel form.
  1: [CONTINUE                     ] Ignore error and continue loading file "C:\\Users\\K\\quicklisp\\dists\\quicklisp\\software\\slime-v2.18\\swank-loader.lisp
".
  2: [ABORT                        ] Abort loading file "C:\\Users\\K\\quicklisp\\dists\\quicklisp\\software\\slime-v2.18\\swank-loader.lisp".
  3: [TRY-RECOMPILING              ] Recompile swank-loader and try loading it again
  4: [RETRY                        ] Retry
                                     loading FASL for #<SWANK-LOADER-FILE "swank" "swank-loader">.
  5: [ACCEPT                       ] Continue, treating
                                     loading FASL for #<SWANK-LOADER-FILE "swank" "swank-loader">
                                     as having been successful.
  6:                                 Retry ASDF operation.
  7: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the
                                     configuration.
  8:                                 Give up on "quicklisp-slime-helper"
  9:                                 Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-IMPL::IMPORT-DIRECTORY #<unavailable argument> NIL)
0]
```

In both error messages, the symbol :COMMA plays a role. I just realized I used this symbol in an own program in an earlier experiment to do with part-of-speech tagging. Could this be a problem?

Finally I tried to install babel, which also failed:

```
* (ql:quickload :babel)
To load "babel":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    alexandria
  Install 2 Quicklisp releases:
    babel trivial-features
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/trivial-features/2015-09-23/trivial-features-20150923-git.tgz">
; 10.26KB
==================================================
10,510 bytes in 0.09 seconds (119.35KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/babel/2015-06-08/babel-20150608-git.tgz">
; 248.03KB
==================================================
253,987 bytes in 1.06 seconds (234.22KB/sec)
; Loading "babel"
[package alexandria]
; file: C:/Users/K/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/alexandria-20160825-git/package.lisp
; in: DEFPACKAGE :ALEXANDRIA
;     (DEFPACKAGE :ALEXANDRIA
;       ()
;       0
;       ()
;       DEV
;       (:NICKNAMES :ALEXANDRIA)
;       (:USE :CL)
;       (:LOCK T)
;       (:EXPORT #:IF-LET
;                #:WHEN-LET
;                #:WHEN-LET*
;                #:CSWITCH
;                #:ESWITCH
;                #:SWITCH
;                #:MULTIPLE-VALUE-PROG2
;                #:NTH-VALUE-OR
;                #:WHICHEVER
;                #:XOR
;                #:DEFINE-CONSTANT
;                ...))
;
; caught ERROR:
;   (during macroexpansion of (DEFPACKAGE :ALEXANDRIA
;     ...))
;   bogus DEFPACKAGE option: NIL

debugger invoked on a UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {100299C713}>:
  COMPILE-FILE-ERROR while compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "alexandria" "package">

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY                        ] Retry
                                     compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "alexandria" "package">.
  1: [ACCEPT                       ] Continue, treating
                                     compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "alexandria" "package">
                                     as having been successful.
  2:                                 Retry ASDF operation.
  3: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the
                                     configuration.
  4: [ABORT                        ] Give up on "babel"
  5:                                 Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(UIOP/LISP-BUILD:CHECK-LISP-COMPILE-RESULTS NIL T T "~/asdf-action::format-action/" ((#<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:COMPILE-OP > . #<ASDF/LISP-ACTION:CL-SOURCE-FILE "alexa
ndria" "package">)))
0] 4
;
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 2 fatal ERROR conditions
;   caught 1 ERROR condition

(:BABEL)
```

Edit 2: Just did the same in Linux (Mint 18 VBox) and received the same versions:

```
* (ql:system-apropos "unicode")
#<SYSTEM cl-ppcre-unicode / cl-ppcre-2.0.11 / quicklisp 2016-08-25>
#<SYSTEM cl-ppcre-unicode-test / cl-ppcre-2.0.11 / quicklisp 2016-08-25>
#<SYSTEM cl-unicode / cl-unicode-0.1.5 / quicklisp 2016-08-25>
#<SYSTEM cl-unicode/base / cl-unicode-0.1.5 / quicklisp 2016-08-25>
#<SYSTEM cl-unicode/build / cl-unicode-0.1.5 / quicklisp 2016-08-25>
#<SYSTEM cl-unicode/test / cl-unicode-0.1.5 / quicklisp 2016-08-25>
#<SYSTEM hu.dwim.syntax-sugar/unicode / hu.dwim.syntax-sugar-20160318-darcs / quicklisp 2016-08-25>
*
```

Only thing I need to know, am I missing something I should know or is it borked? I want to work with it and learn Lisp, not fix installation issues.

Edit 3: Thanks to the hint to check integrity of the readtable, it now works:

```
* (setq *readtable* (copy-readtable nil))

#<READTABLE {100569BA23}>
* (ql:quickload :cl-unicode)
To load "cl-unicode":
  Install 1 Quicklisp release:
    cl-unicode
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/cl-unicode/2014-12-17/cl-unicode-0.1.5.tgz">
; 474.62KB
==================================================
486,011 bytes in 1.80 seconds (264.27KB/sec)
; Loading "cl-unicode"
[package cl-unicode]..............................
[package cl-unicode-names]....................
(:CL-UNICODE)
*
```

It remains a mystery why the old version of cl-unicode keeps getting pulled, and why the same problem occurred on another box with no history of tinkering. But I'm satisfied for now. Thanks to all who took the time to respond.

Comment: Hmm .. Looking at the source https://github.com/edicl/cl-unicode/blob/master/util.lisp#L152 it seems as if the backquote (and thus the commas) don't get evaluated. Strange...

Comment: With `(ql:quickload :cl-unicode)` I'm getting a different error: `no symbol named "*STANDARD-OPTIMIZE-SETTINGS*" in "CL-PPCRE"`.

Comment: when this happened to me it turned out I had a really old version of CL-PPCRE in my local projects - it was downloaded with the practical common lisp code. I would check that you are indeed loading what you think you are loading with (ql:where-is-system "cl-ppcre")

Comment: @DavidHodge That yields
#P"C:/Users/K/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl-ppcre-2.0.11/"
The entire installation of my Lisp system is less than a month old. - Just realized, you were replying to Renzo I suppose.

Comment: @user1604027, thanks, it is exactly that the problem for me!

Comment: I'll just throw in the mostly-unhelpful, “it does work for me” (SBCL "1.3.4-1.fc24" stock build from Fedora 24 repos).

Comment: @Old Tortoise If indeed you have a version mismatch between CL-PPCRE and CL-UNICODE  the first thing to check is that you are loading the expected versions. My installation works with CL-PPCRE 2.0.11 and CL-UNICODE 1.2.4 Which is a relatively recent version in quicklisp. Your log shows CL-UNICODE 0.1.5 which is quite old and this is likely the problem.  When was the last time you updated quicklisp?

Comment: @DavidHodge As said above, the entire installation is quite new. If the cl-unicode version is an old one, then it got pulled by the system. Which means the same will happen again if I re-install everything from scratch. Searching for a way to update cl-unicode, I found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/quicklisp/b0gKa-wlvBU "There isn't a way to update individual projects within a set in
Quicklisp. They are all versioned together." But your cited version numbers also don't match, which means I would have to check every single library at its source to see whether it's the latest.

Comment: My unhelpful point: roswell + sbcl-bin 1.3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04, loading `cl-unicode` works. Can you post the part of `cl-unicode/util.lisp` where it defines constant `:COMMA`? You can find it in `~/.roswell/lisp/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software` for roswell and `~/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software` for usual quicklisp installation (`~` is your home directory).

Comment: I have the same version of `cl-unicode`. I found the constant is generated in macro `DEFINE-HANGUL-CONSTANT`. Copy and evaluate this macro and check what macro-expansions it gives you. Somehow comma splicing doesn't work in your installation. Or copy the macro here. Have you install anything that might have altered a read-table?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that "experiment" of yours? If you accidentally altered the readtable, then this might be the issue.

Comment: @mobiuseng Does it make sense to try and debug old code rather than find out why it gets installed at all instead of the latest version?

Comment: @DanielJour Thx for the hint. I did play with some reader macros once, I'll have a look if I accidentally did something with a comma, if so it was not intended. Will be a little later this weekend till I can get to it. But strange is, the same thing happened in two different installations. I haven't done any such tinkering in the Linux vbox.